# Getting Java to work with Windows 10 Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, windows-10

I installed the Windows 10 Anniversary Update so that I could try Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.  See [how to install it](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/).  I wanted to see how performant it was.  I then installed the Oracle Java JDK as per [this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux), so I could compare compilation times with the native Windows Java compiler.

I then tried to run Maven on my project, but it didn't work.  Maven just hung starting.  I noticed in Task Manager that the "java" process was hovering around 92% CPU.

So I tried something simple.  I created a dummy Java Hello-world-like class and attempted to compile it with javac.  Similarly, the "javac" process sat around 92% CPU.

I thought maybe it had something to do with running headless, but the `-Djava.awt.headless=true`option didn't make it any better.

Has anyone got this to work or have anything to try?

**Update:**

I also tried installing the Open JDK instead of the Oracle JDK (via `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`) with the same result.

Comment: From the link to install Bash there is this sentence: "Not every command-line application will work, either, as this feature is still in beta." I don't know how valid it still is since the article is 6 months old, but it might still have some truth.

Comment: Some ideas: (1) Have you tried running it under gdb and getting a backtrace once it hangs? (2) Does it help if you pass `-J-Xint` to javac so that the JVM disables the JIT compiler?

Comment: My comment is gone. If you have any question, simply put a comment under one of my question or answers. And don't get me wrong : I only posted here because that was a quick way to get that message to you :-)

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  I couldn't use the download directly from Oracle.  Instead I had to install it as per [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).  Here are the steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. The first Fast Track Insider Build after the Anniversary Update and later support both the oracle Java 8 installer and the open JDK 7 installer. I just verified the java -version command still works on Insider Preview Build 14951 161014-1700 from the Ubuntu subsystem's bash shell. I have run other JVM based tools from bash shell as well but not extensively.

Here is a link to an issue, [Cannot install Oracle JDK 8 #315](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/315), describing both installation and JVM hang issues tracked by the [BashOnWindows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows) project.