# Javac on Ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm on windows 10 and running the bash shell (ubuntu), by turning the Windows Subsystem for linux on. Anyways, I'm trying to run some Java programs through the command prompt. I have already set the PATH variables and I can successfully run the java and javac commands in the windows command prompt. However, when I run the javac or java command using Ubuntu shell it says those commands are not found? So it lists some options that I can enter and one of those is

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

But when I run this command it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

I don't get it. I already have Java-8 installed and the PATH variables set, it works fine for the windows command prompt but fails to work with ubuntu. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use the OpenJDK version?  Try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155174/getting-java-to-work-with-windows-10-ubuntu/40324807#40324807) and [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/315)

Comment: Yes I found these same commands from another post and it works fine now. Quick question though, do you know how I can launch gedit from the ubuntu terminal? I installed it via terminal but whenever I try to use the command I get "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused". Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You would need to install an XWindow server like XMing and start it up. Then in your terminal window, do `export DISPLAY=:0` before launching gedit.